# How to increase CIBIL score?

Tags: india, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

How to increase cibil score if your credit card and personal repayment history are not consistently good?

Answer (score 1):

> if your credit card and personal repayment history are not consistently good?

This will be a long process. You will have to make previous repayments and over the period of 4-5 years the score improves. There is no shortcut.

Comment: Any agencies will help you to do that

Answer (score 1):

There's no such hack. Trying to improve your CIBIL score is a gradual process.

As a wise man once said "Patience is the key to SUCCESS"

There are ways to get back on the road to good credit health. Here are 2 ways to help build your credit score:

1. Ensure you clear outstanding dues on credit cards fully: Part-payments or minimum payments indicate difficulties in repaying dues. What's more, if your amount overdue snowballs it not only affects your CIBIL score negatively but also risks falling into a debt trap. Also, if a pending credit card payment is reported as "Settled" or "Written Off" this will affect your access to credit in the future.
2. If you have the amount pending on multiple cards, taking a personal loan at a lower interest rate to pay off your cumulative dues can be an economical option to avoid ballooning debt balances. Alternatively, you can borrow money against your gold, take a loan against your fixed deposit (don't break it) or even get a loan of 50-80% of your asset value from investments in LIC, mutual funds, and securities. The lower interest rate will make for more manageable monthly payments without the problem of an exponentially ballooning debt burden.

While these measures help rebuild your credit health after missed payments, adopting a proactive approach to financial discipline is always more prudent.

- Make sure to pay on time
- Don't take on more debt than you can reasonably afford

So, while missed payments can negatively affect your credit score, regular payments and credit-healthy habits can improve it. This should help. Good Luck!